# Access groupby value within apply

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How can I access the `groupby` value from within the function I pass to `apply`?
Here's an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("bird", "Falconiformes", 389.0),
        ("bird", "Psittaciformes", 24.0),
        ("mammal", "Carnivora", 80.2),
        ("mammal", "Primates", 20),
        ("mammal", "Carnivora", 58),
    ],
    index=["falcon", "parrot", "lion", "monkey", "leopard"],
    columns=("class", "order", "max_speed"),
)

class_to_features = {"bird": ["wings", "feathers", "beak"], "mammal": ["udder"]}


def _helper(df):
    # Here I'd like to access the value of the class
    # One option is `print(df.iloc[0]["class"]`
    # but it seems very non-Pythonic
    # return class_to_features[df["class"]]
    print(class_to_features[df["class"].iloc[0]])


df.groupby("class", as_index=False).apply(_helper)
```

In the `_helper` function, I'd like to access the value of the `groupby` field (in this case `"bird"` and `"mammal"`). I can do it like shown in the code, but I'm looking for a more Pythonic or Pandasic way.

Comment: you can just use df["class"]. Printing returns the full object. in a an apply function, each access to df.class is one element, you can see that by using return df.class after your print statement

Comment: `df["class"]` is a Series object. Of course all the values in the Series are identical, and I'm looking for the most Pythonic way to get that value.

Comment: If you use `df.apply(_helper, axis=1)` instead of `df.groupby.apply` then `df['class']` inside `_helper` will actually refer to each individual value in the class column and not the whole series.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe looks like this:

```py
          class           order  max_speed
falcon     bird   Falconiformes      389.0
parrot     bird  Psittaciformes       24.0
lion     mammal       Carnivora       80.2
monkey   mammal        Primates       20.0
leopard  mammal       Carnivora       58.0
```

`df.groupby("class").apply()` function accesses the dataframe of each category (bird, mammal) in the "class" column.

so, The function you want to apply to the divided dataframe is defined in the `_helper`.
If you tell me what type of result you want to make, i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can access each groupby object with the following:

```
class_to_features = {"bird": ["wings", "feathers", "beak"], "mammal": ["udder"]}

for group_id, group_df in df.groupby("class", as_index=False):
    # Print the features by mapping the dictionary   
    print(class_to_features[group_id])

# You can also map the values from the dictionary directly to the original dataframe:
df['features_list'] = df['class'].map(class_to_features)
```

Comment: Yes, but that's by using a `for` loop. Can I do it by using `apply`?

Comment: What is the desired output @Gino

Comment: It's less about the output and more about a way to access the grouped-by value. In my specific case, I need to access a dictionary and do some calculations.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't the `group_df` work in the loop? This for loop is what's taking place in the backend when you run a `groupby` function in pandas...

Comment: Well, in the spirit of code abstraction, I'd like to code *what* I need instead of *how* to do it. `apply` is exactly that, but since as far as I can tell there's no way to do what I want, so I'll do a loop.

Comment: Sadly, our realities depend on the manifestations of abstractions not the abstractions themselves @Gino.